# Lag a variable with non unique id x time observations

Tags: stata

I have a repeated cross section every year. I have a variable, `var1`, which is the same across all observations in a given year (for instance, the mean of a variable in a given year). I'd like to create a variable, `var1_l`, that would be the lagged version of `var1`.

As an example, from the dataset

```
  id1   year    var1
   3    1990     3.5
   4    1990     3.5
   5    1991       4
   6    1991       4
   7    1991       4
```

I would like to obtain

```
  id1   year    var1 var1_l
   3    1990     3.5      .
   4    1990     3.5      .
   5    1991       4    3.5
   6    1991       4    3.5
   7    1991       4    3.5
```

A solution would be to use a `merge` but saving/restoring the dataset takes a lot of time when the dataset is big. For reference, below is my current `merge` solution:

```
preserve
keep year var1
replace year = year - 1
bys year: keep if _n == 1
rename var1 var1_l
sort year
tempfile temp
save `temp'
restore
merge m:1 year using `temp', nogen sorted
```

Another option would be to use the matrix returned by `tabstat`. I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution (that returns . when there is no observation in year - 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems a little unusual, but could be just a twist on a standard problem  [as explained here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/index.html).

```
. input id1   year    var1

           id1       year       var1
  1.    3    1990     3.5
  2.    4    1990     3.5
  3.    5    1991       4
  4.    6    1991       4
  5.    7    1991       4
  6. end 

. sort year id1 

. generate var1_l = var1[_n-1] if year == year[_n-1] + 1
(4 missing values generated)

. replace var1_l = var1_l[_n-1] if year == year[_n-1] & missing(var1_l) 
(2 real changes made)

. list 

     +----------------------------+
     | id1   year   var1   var1_l |
     |----------------------------|
  1. |   3   1990    3.5        . |
  2. |   4   1990    3.5        . |
  3. |   5   1991      4      3.5 |
  4. |   6   1991      4      3.5 |
  5. |   7   1991      4      3.5 |
     +----------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. But there is no elegant way to extend it for year - 2 right?

Comment: What would be the extension? Either the lagged value is undefined when the step is two years or more (no change to code) or you use previous known value, in which case `if year == year[_n-1] + 1` would just be `if year != year[_n-1]`.

Comment: If I want to compute a n-year lag (similarly to Ln.), I would need to create successively n variables, right?

Comment: Question creep! I think you'd need a different sort order, but in principle if you want several variables, you need to create them all.

Answer (score 3):

This answer crossed with @Nick's but there's a slight difference in terms of results. I check only that `year`s be different, while his code checks that `year`s be consecutive.

```
clear 
set more off

input ///
id year var1
1 1990 3.5
3 1990 3.5
2 1990 3.5
1 1991 2
2 1991 2
3 1991 2
3 1992 6
2 1992 6
1 1992 6
3 1993 6
2 1993 6
1 1993 6
4 1993 6
1 1994 4.3
2 1994 4.3
3 1994 4.3
end

list, sepby(year)

*----- what you want -----

sort year

generate var2 = var1[_n-1] if year != year[_n-1]
by year : replace var2 = var2[1]

list, sepby(year)
```